# Gnuplot: Plotting different colors to each point using xticlabels and linepoints

Tags: plot, gnuplot, point, lines, palette

I'm trying to plot a graph with linepoints and the first column is a string and a I need to use xticlabels to plot the data to the second column related to it.

This is my data file, the third column I wish to use the set the point color

```
"0000"  0   0
"0001"  9   0
"0010"  16  0
"0011"  25  1
"0100"  14  0
"0101"  23  0
"0110"  30  0
"0111"  39  1
"1000"  30  0
"1001"  39  0
"1010"  46  2
"1100"  44  0
```

I used:

```
set palette defined (0 "blue", 1 "yellow", 2 "red")
plot "data.dat" using 2:xticlabels(1) with linespoints ls 1 notitle
```

How can I change this command to plot each point color to use the appropriate point color?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you need:

```
plot "data.dat" using 0:2:3:xticlabels(1) with linespoints ls 1 lc palette notitle
```

Comment: thanks, but that colored the lines too, can it colour just the points?

rendered something like that http://i.imgur.com/6Os4MKP.png

Comment: you have to use 2 plot commands: `plot "data.dat" using 0:2:3:xticlabels(1) with lines lc rgb "black" notitle, '' using 0:2:3:xticlabels(1) w points lc palette notitle`

Comment: If you dont mind, you know how I can remove that palette subtitle and add a custom one, where I can just pinpoint the difference between the blue, orange and red points. Just to explain what every point means?

The graph is ploted like that now: http://s21.postimg.org/g61c8ipl3/Sem_t_tulo.png